# Remove single word entries from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to know how to remove a single word entry from an array full of multi-word entries. Here is an example of the array:

**INPUT:**

```
[ "Off the bloody wall", "who?", "That sounds familiar" , "lol", "what the hell"  ]
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
[ "Off the bloody wall", "That sounds familiar" , "what the hell"  ]
```

I could put together a multi-stage solution to this, but perhaps someone here knows of a quick one-line jQuery solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.protype.filter` to remove elements that do not pass a predicate function, and `String.prototype.match` to test a string for a match. In this case we filter the out the property if it doesn't have a space.

```js
const arr = [ "Off the bloody wall", "who?", "That sounds familiar" , "lol", "what the hell"  ]

console.log(
  arr.filter(item => item.match(' '))
)
```